# creating a jumbled up word game in python

Tags: python

I am at beginner level in python. And I am trying to do a game in python, call Jumble Up words game. I have "words.txt" which is include all words for game and "High_score.txt", to store the highest score that player get. I want to know how can i load those ".txt" files in which data structures. And how to generate 8 random letters from a-z for the players to guess. The game is like program will give the user 8 random letters and player can guess from 2-8 letters that match with the words in "words.txt". And stores the 30 highest scores in "High_score.txt" file.

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Comment: In general, the best way to use this site is to first read the manual or at least show us what you have tried before posting a question. That said, I have posted some answers.

Comment: Hard to tell without the code but you should look into the standard library modules `pickle`(for storing data structures in files) and `random`(for generating random values) and the built-in function `open`(to read from and write data to files).

Answer (score 1):

Read a file:

```py
f = open("/path/to/file","r")
string = f.read()
```

Random letters:

```
import string
import random
mixedletters = ''.join(random.sample(s, len(s)))
```